# Spring mvc form validation using hibernate validator

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, hibernate-validator

How to display a custom message or remove input for integer field in jsp form when user enters white-space in input-field in spring mvc, validated using hibernate validator?
It currently shows:

**Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
 type int for property freePasses; nested exception is
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""**

Comment: Use bootsrap or jquery validator in front end

Comment: Yes , that is an alternative but  what if I want to show custom message using java in controller side?

Comment: Use @NotNull annotation.

Comment: @NotNull working for String fields , displaying custom message as required,but for int fields still showing same :Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property freePasses; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Use wrapper class to declare integer varieble. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211734/hibernate-validation-annotation-validate-that-at-least-one-field-is-not-null

Comment: Oh yes ,got it ,working,since wrapper class will convert whitespace to null.thanks

Comment: Welcome..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wrapper class to declare integer variables so that wrapper class will convert whitespace to null.

or

refer below link for common solution

[Hibernate validation annotation - validate that at least one field is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211734/hibernate-validation-annotation-validate-that-at-least-one-field-is-not-null)